# Why IPPROTO_DIVERT in C stop working after a few tests?

Tags: c, macos, sockets, ipfw

I am developing an application (got the code from [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Divert-Sockets-mini-HOWTO.html)) to show the content of network packets in OS X using C and here is my code:

```
/* open a divert socket */
fd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_DIVERT);

if (fd==-1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"We could not open a divert socket\n");
    exit(1);
}

bindPort.sin_family=AF_INET;
bindPort.sin_port=htons(5060);
bindPort.sin_addr.s_addr=0;

fprintf(stderr,"Binding a socket\n");
ret=bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&bindPort, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

if (ret!=0) {
    close(fd);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error bind(): %s",strerror(ret));
    exit(2);
}
/* read data in */
sinlen=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
while (1) {
    n = (int)recvfrom(fd, packet, 1514, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, (socklen_t*)&sinlen);
    hdr = (struct ip *) packet;
    fprintf(stdout, "\n{{packet size: [%d]}}\n", htons(hdr->ip_len));fflush(stdout);
    printf("The packet looks like this:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", (int)*(packet + i));
        if (!((i + 1) % 16))
            printf("\n");
    };
    printf("\n");

    printf("Source address: %s\n",  inet_ntoa(hdr->ip_src));
    printf("Destination address: %s\n",  inet_ntoa(hdr->ip_dst));
    printf("Receiving IF address: %s\n",  inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr));
    printf("Protocol number: %i\n", hdr->ip_p);
}
```

Before I run the code, I run the following command:

```
ipfw add divert 5060 all from any to 192.168.1.34
```

The problem with the code is that it is not reliable. It sometimes works and sometimes does not. I have to reboot the machine and then it works (but only for a few times). Is there any other way to send the packets from kernel space to the user-space? Ultimately, I want to change the packet and re-inject them to the network flow.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that resolves the problem.

pfctl -d    //this command will let you use ipfw without any problem.

PS: IPFW is depricated in Yosemite!